# Text boxes are not shown dynamically according the ui flags with the condition in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Only one text box is shown according to the condition

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <button id = "btn-append-to-body" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Products
        <span class="caret">
        </span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" dropdown-menu role="menu">
        <li ng-repeat="releaseSchedule in releaseSchedules">
            <a href="" ng-click="oldOption(releaseSchedule)">{{releaseSchedule.product}}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>
            <a href="" ng-click="newOption('New')">Create new</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control formgroup" ng-show="productSelect" disabled>
    <input type="text" class="form-control formgroup" ng-show="newSelect">
</div>
```

The angular function to change flags:

```
$scope.newOption = function(releaseSchedule) {    
    $scope.newSelect = true;
    $scope.oldSelect = false;
};

$scope.oldOption = function(releaseSchedule) {
    $scope.oldSelect = true;
    $scope.newSelect = false;
};
```

When I crick the create new static listing from the dropdown the one text box is shown. But when I click the dynamically generated options the disabled textbox mentioned in the code is not shown.

Comment: Can you please add a sample of your `releaseSchedules` array?

Comment: [
  {
    "_id": "580e4dbc1de6fd503e30bded",
    "createdOn": "2016-10-24T18:06:52.292Z",
    "quarter": "Q4",
    "year": "2017-2018",
    "product": "Apple",
    "version": "1.9",
    "releaseDate": "2017-01-05T18:30:00.000Z",
    "comment": "testing",
    "__v": 0,
    "modifiedOn": "2016-10-25T07:09:51.896Z"
  }
]